# Getting something different than standard nesting resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if it would be possible to nest resources differently than what I usually see.

Usually, resources go something like this:

```
resources :article do
  resources :comment 
end
```

And this produces the URL `/article/:article_id/comment`   [for comment#index, of course]

However, I'm wondering if I could do this differently to get something like

```
/article/comment   [excluding :article_id]
```

Article would have all of its other normal routes, and comment would behave as it would in the first example. Is there a way to do this, so that I could keep /comment connected with comments_controller, or do I need to relocate all of the comment methods into the articles_controller? I'd prefer to avoid that, because it causes headaches later.

**You're probably asking why I'd ever need to do this in this context. Truth is, I'm doing it in a different context, but this one is easier to explain.

EDIT:

The real purpose is different than the example. I want a controller, 'employee_benefits', to be a regular controller and have regular resources. However, I'd like to be able to do something like /employee_benefits/new_type. A type of benefit is something that appears in the form when creating a new employee_benefit. I'd like to be able to do things like /employee_benefits/edit_type[:id], /employee_benefits/delete [well not exactly]

I think namespacing is the way to go, but I'm not completely sure how to do it.

More EDIT:

I'm currently using these resources:

```
  match '/benefits/new_type' => 'company_benefits#new_type'
  match '/benefits/create_type' => 'company_benefits#create_type'
  match '/benefits/types' => 'company_benefits#types'
  match '/benefits/type' => 'company_benefits#types'
```

Instead of

```
  resources :company_benefits, :path => '/benefits', :as => :benefits do 
    <not using this line of code>
    resources :company_benefit_types
    </not using this line of code>
  end
```

Comment: Is there more than one `article`? If so, how do you know which one's `comments` to show?

Comment: I'm a bit confused; without knowing which article you're referencing, which comments would you display?

Comment: Yes, there is more than 1 article. The purpose of this is to create a 'type', or 'category' of article. On creating an article, the form gives the option to select a type. I would like the types to be pre-made, and this is the feature that lets you pre-make the types

Comment: Are you saying that "comment" is the type of article, not that an article has many comments?

Comment: How will you differentiate between a valid ID and a type? You could do so via routing mechanisms, but IMO that's starting to get too "trick"y. And *why* do you want to do it like this?

Comment: Well, sort of. I have a model called EmployeeBenefitTypes, a controller (which I'm not currently using, because I'm putting the logic in a different controller), and views, which are decendants of the controller I just spoke about

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. It's weird. But I want to be able to create types without specifying the article. Types are generic

Comment: @MikeDunnegan Then it shouldn't be related to articles at all.

Comment: Well hold on, I don't mean that they're THAT generic. They definitely need to be related to articles, because articles are the only things that have types. I don't want to go through the typical process of creating an article, and then creating a type connected to it. Upon creating an article, I need to be able to select a type from a collection. Types are dynamic. Should I use nested resources?

Comment: @MikeDunnegan Please use **@** replies. If they're only related to one thing then there's no reason to differentiate between... the one thing they're related to. I don't even see why you need nested resources at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into the namespace examples and essentially prefix your comment routes with "/article".  That would create the routes you want - although I do encourage you to think on it and make sure removing article id is what you want.

Shallow nesting may work well for you too - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

EDIT:

It sounds like what you want would look like this in rails 2:

```
resources :company_benefit_types, :path_prefix => "/benefits"
```

In rails 3 it would look like this:

```
scope "/benefits" do
    resources :company_benefit_types
end
```

Check the output by running `bundle exec rake routes` to see what it looks like.

```
   company_benefit_types GET    /benefits/company_benefit_types(.:format)          company_benefit_types#index
                          POST   /benefits/company_benefit_types(.:format)          company_benefit_types#create
 new_company_benefit_type GET    /benefits/company_benefit_types/new(.:format)      company_benefit_types#new
edit_company_benefit_type GET    /benefits/company_benefit_types/:id/edit(.:format) company_benefit_types#edit
     company_benefit_type GET    /benefits/company_benefit_types/:id(.:format)      company_benefit_types#show
                          PUT    /benefits/company_benefit_types/:id(.:format)      company_benefit_types#update
                          DELETE /benefits/company_benefit_types/:id(.:format)      company_benefit_types#destroy
```

Comment: actually that makes a fair amount of sense to me. is there a way to do this, while still using resources instead of matches?

Comment: Yes, good question.  I've updated my answer to show how that would work.

Answer (score -1):

This should help you (note that I left the plural 's' out):

```
resource :article do
    resource :comment
end
```

And actually what you wrote up there will produce `articles/:article_id/comments`.